# How to convert this array of objects to use reduce javascript

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm trying to convert this function to use reduce. I am halfway through. When the selected value is `true` I want to know the index of that element.

```
let options = [
    {label: 'foo1', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: true},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
];
const obj = options
              .map((option, index) => (option.selected ? index : -1))
              .filter((val) => val !== -1)[0];
```

Result: `1`

My attempt is this:

```
const obj = options.reduce((acc, currentValue, index) => {
    const i = currentValue["selected"] ? index : -1;
    return acc.concat(i)
}, []); // [-1,1,-1,-1,-1]
```

How do I change the entire thing to use reduce?

Comment: is it an assigned home work to use reduce? Because I feel a simple loop is good here. or you can use options.findIndex(x=>x.selected)

Answer (score 1):

Add the index to the result only if `option.selected` is true otherwise do nothing.

```js
let options = [
    {label: 'foo1', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: true},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
];

const selected = options.reduce((arr, option, index) => {
  return option.selected ? arr.concat(index) : arr; 
}, []);

console.log(selected);
```

Comment: From how I understand his question that's his current output and the expected output should be the same if he would use `map` + `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary in `concat()` to set the value to be inserted. `Array#concat()` returns the updated array so that is the return for `reduce()`.

Or use spread to return new array `[...accumulator, selsected ? i :-1]`

```js
const res = options.reduce((a, {selected:s}, i) =>  a.concat(s ? i : -1) , []);

// OR
// const res = options.reduce((a, {selected:s}, i) =>  [....a,s ? i : -1] , []);

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>

let options = [
    {label: 'foo1', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: true},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
];

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want indexes with `selected` = true, then you could do something like this using `reduce`. If the current item in context has `selected` === true, add the index to the accumulator, else return the accumulator. Currently, you're adding `-1` if the condition is `false`

```js
let options = [
    {label: 'foo1', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: true},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
];

const selectedIndexes = options.reduce((r, o, i) => o.selected ? r.concat(i) : r, [])
console.log(selectedIndexes)
```

If you want the whole object, then you can simply use `filter`:

```js
let options = [{label:'foo1',selected:false},{label:'foo2',selected:true},{label:'foo2',selected:false},{label:'foo2',selected:false},{label:'foo2',selected:false},];

const filtered = options.filter(o => o.selected)
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and the `...` spread operator keep the existing indexes and add the new index if `selected` is `true`.

```js
let options = [
    {label: 'foo1', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: true},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: true},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: 1}
];

const obj = options.reduce((acc, currentValue, index) => {
    // checking only for boolean true not for truthy values
    return acc = currentValue["selected"] === true ? [...acc, index] : acc;
}, []); 
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Another way is use of `push` instead of `concat` :***

```js
let options = [
    {label: 'foo1', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: true},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
    {label: 'foo2', selected: false},
];

var obj = options.reduce( (acc, currentValue, index) => {
    currentValue.selected ? acc.push(index) : ''; return acc} ,[] ) ;

console.log(obj)
```